# Trying to create multiple PDF for each row in a Google Sheet

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a separate PDF for each row in a Google Sheet using a Google Doc as a template. I can get it to work when I use the active row; however, when I try to loop the createpdf function the only PDF I am left with is the last row. My thoughts are that I am deleting all of the files beforehand but I can't figure out where the error is. Any help would be awesome.

```
var TEMPLATE_ID = '1Mxrm0kny8R7ROlBou8kSUc8dOvvH8PvtQ-EC_Nd3FUQ';

function onOpen() {

 SpreadsheetApp
  .getUi()
  .createMenu('Create PDF')
  .addItem('Create PDF', 'createPdf')
  .addToUi();
} 

for (var i=2; i < 3; i++) { function createPdf() {

  if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('TEMPLATE_ID needs to be defined in code.gs');
  return;
 }

// Set up the docs and the spreadsheet access

var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
   copyId = copyFile.getId(),
   copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
   copyBody = copyDoc.getBody(),
   activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
   numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn(),
   activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
   headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
   columnIndex = 0,
   fileName =  activeRow[0][0] + activeRow[0][1],
   pdfFile,
   pdfFile2;

 // Replace the keys with the spreadsheet values

for (;columnIndex < headerRow[0].length; columnIndex++) {

  copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][columnIndex] + '%', 
                     activeRow[0][columnIndex]);                         
 }

// Create the PDF file and delete the doc copy

 copyDoc.saveAndClose();

 pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs("application/pdf"));

 pdfFile2 = pdfFile.setName(fileName)

 copyFile.setTrashed(true);

 return pdfFile2;

                  }}
```

Comment: Too bad this was mis-tagged, that kept it from being seen by folks that could help. (Actually, pretty much made it invisible, just 10 views in 4 months.)

Answer (score 0):

Tip: pay attention to formatting your code properly, because it will help you understand its structure. Here's what you have after passing it through [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/):

```js
var TEMPLATE_ID = '1Mxrm0kny8R7ROlBou8kSUc8dOvvH8PvtQ-EC_Nd3FUQ';

function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu('Create PDF')
    .addItem('Create PDF', 'createPdf')
    .addToUi();
}

for (var i = 2; i < 3; i++) {
  function createPdf() {

    if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') {

      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('TEMPLATE_ID needs to be defined in code.gs');
      return;
    }

    // Set up the docs and the spreadsheet access

    var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
      copyId = copyFile.getId(),
      copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
      copyBody = copyDoc.getBody(),
      activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn(),
      activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
      headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
      columnIndex = 0,
      fileName = activeRow[0][0] + activeRow[0][1],
      pdfFile,
      pdfFile2;

    // Replace the keys with the spreadsheet values

    for (; columnIndex < headerRow[0].length; columnIndex++) {

      copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][columnIndex] + '%',
        activeRow[0][columnIndex]);
    }

    // Create the PDF file and delete the doc copy

    copyDoc.saveAndClose();

    pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs("application/pdf"));

    pdfFile2 = pdfFile.setName(fileName)

    copyFile.setTrashed(true);

    return pdfFile2;

  }
}
```

The indenting clarifies a few problems:

- The `for` loop on `i` is in *global* scope, not part of any function. It will therefore execute every time ANY function in the script is invoked, but is not explicitly invocable, as it would be in a function.
- The function `createPDF` is declared inside that `for` loop. This is in global scope (see point 1), so it's still available to be called from other functions such as the menu created by your `onOpen()`. HOWEVER, because it's just a declaration, it is NOT invoked by the `i loop`! (This was the primary concern of your question.)
- There's a `return` call inside `createPdf()` that is probably a left-over from the original copy of this code which produced a single PDF. Because it returns in the first time through the loop, it will STILL make a single PDF. That line needs to be moved or deleted.

  ```js
  return pdfFile2;
  ```

Flipping those couple of lines and deleting the `return` should sort us out.

```js
var TEMPLATE_ID = '1Mxrm0kny8R7ROlBou8kSUc8dOvvH8PvtQ-EC_Nd3FUQ';

function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu('Create PDF')
    .addItem('Create PDF', 'createPdf')
    .addToUi();
}

function createPdf() {
  for (var i = 2; i < 3; i++) {

    if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') {

      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('TEMPLATE_ID needs to be defined in code.gs');
      return;
    }

    // Set up the docs and the spreadsheet access

    var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
      copyId = copyFile.getId(),
      copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
      copyBody = copyDoc.getBody(),
      activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn(),
      activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
      headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
      columnIndex = 0,
      fileName = activeRow[0][0] + activeRow[0][1],
      pdfFile,
      pdfFile2;

    // Replace the keys with the spreadsheet values

    for (; columnIndex < headerRow[0].length; columnIndex++) {

      copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][columnIndex] + '%',
        activeRow[0][columnIndex]);
    }

    // Create the PDF file and delete the doc copy

    copyDoc.saveAndClose();

    pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs("application/pdf"));

    pdfFile2 = pdfFile.setName(fileName)

    copyFile.setTrashed(true);

  }
}
```